# Rendering through blender looks fine, but not through SheepIt

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

I'm using SheepIt! to render a 501-frame-long 1280x720 scene I'm working on. Right now I'm the only one rendering and, and I noticed something weird. Rendering through SheepIt! produces a weird purple and pink image...[image]

Rendering that exact frame (on the exact same file) produces this; [image]

which is exactly what i need. Anyone know whats going on?

Answer (score 3):

You need to embed your images into you blend. [image]